# gradle could not find other gradle script

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

```
/--common
/--common/build.gradle
/--common/deploy.gradle
/--project1
/--project1/build.gradle
```

I have a multi-project structure and have extracted repeating code from my `build.gradle` file and placed this into another file `deploy.gradle`.

I have placed the `deploy.gradle` file into the `common` project at the same folder level as the `build.gradle` file. The folder structure is shown above.

In the `build.gradle` file of the `common` project I can reference the file using the statement,

```
apply from: 'deploy.gradle'
```

This works like a dream and the `common` project build works perfectly calling in the tasks from the `deploy.gradle` file.

The problem comes when I try to reference `deploy.gradle` file from one of the other projects. When I add the `apply...` statement to the `build.gradle` of  `project1` I get the compilation error,

> Error:(23, 0) Could not read script
>   'C:\path-to-project1-script-file\deploy.gradle' as it does not exist.

So Gradle is looking for the `deploy.gradle` file in `project1` only even though I have a dependency set to the `common` project in the `project1` `build.gradle` file.

Question is how can I make `deploy.gradle` from `common` project visible to `project1`.

Answer (score 5):

We successfully use the following project layout

```
├── a
│   └── build.gradle
├── b
│   └── build.gradle
├── build.gradle
├── gradle-scripts
│   └── deploy.gradle
└── settings.gradle
```

The rootproject's `build.gradle` defines

```
ext.gradleScript = { scriptName ->
    file("${rootProject.projectDir}/gradle-scripts/${scriptName}.gradle")
}
```

Subprojects use the scripts within `gradle-scripts` this way

```
apply from: gradleScript('deploy')
```

Whole content of the project:

```
$> find . -type f | while read file; do echo "--- $file ---" && cat $file; done
--- ./a/build.gradle ---
apply from: gradleScript('deploy')
--- ./b/build.gradle ---
apply from: gradleScript('deploy')
--- ./build.gradle ---
// Where common build logic is found
ext.gradleScript = { scriptName ->
    file("${rootProject.projectDir}/gradle-scripts/${scriptName}.gradle")
}
--- ./gradle-scripts/deploy.gradle ---
task myDeployTask {
    doLast { println 'common deploy logic goes here' }
}
--- ./settings.gradle ---
include 'a', 'b'

$> gradle -q b:myDeployTask
common deploy logic goes here
$>
```

Comment: thank you Frank. I am trying this approach but getting an error message from #a/build.gradle that it cant find the gradleScript - do I have to include something in the settings.gradle file or in my Intellij project configuration ? I notice you specify "${rootProject.projectDir}/" does this need to be set in the settings.gradle file as a property/value pair and if so how would I specify that as a relative path ? an example would be helpful if you can

Comment: I added the complete content of the demo project and a sample gradle call. Did you include your projects in `settings.gradle`?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example `project1/build.gradle` that references `common/deploy.gradle`:

```
// import myDeploy task
apply from: "${rootDir}/common/deploy.gradle"

task myProject1Task(dependsOn: 'myDeploy') {
    doLast {
        println 'TRACER myProject1Task'
    }
}
```

It is often important to distinguish `projectDir` from `rootDir` in multi-project builds. `projectDir` is the specific subproject; `rootDir` is where `settings.gradle` lives.

Comment: Hi Micheal, thank you for your answer. I am trying this approach but having problems setting the rootDir. My projects only seem to recognise the directory that it is in i.e when I am working in common rootDir = common or when I am in project1 then rootDir = project1 - I cant seem to configure the projects to recognise the level above the the project that I am in and so I cant access the common directory in the other project.

Comment: Do you have a `settings.gradle` file? I have posted my example here - https://github.com/codetojoy/easter_eggs_for_gradle/tree/master/egg_StackOverflow_47701148